# Ignoring a JSON field in Haskell Aeson input

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have a Haskell record

```hs
data User = User
    { email :: Text
    , token :: Text
    }
```

and I want to ignore the value of "token" in any input JSON. For example, if the input JSON is

```
{
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "token": "abc123"
}
```

I want the resulting `User` object to contain `User { email = "foo@bar.com", token = "" }`.

I defined the following:

```hs
instance FromJSON User where
    parseJSON (Object v) =
        User <$> v .:  "email"
             <*> v .:? "" .!= "" -- token

    parseJSON _ = fail "Invalid User"
```

Is there a better way to set the value of the `token` field then `v .:? "" .!= ""`, ignoring the `"token": "abc123"` in the JSON?

I tried

```hs
instance FromJSON User where
    parseJSON (Object v) =
        User <$> v .:  "email"
             <*> "" -- token

    parseJSON _ = fail "Invalid User"
```

but it will not compile because the `<*> ""` needs to be a `Parser Text`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this one?

```
User <$> v .: "email" <*> pure ""
```

The `pure` function comes from `Control.Applicative` module. In this case it constructs a trivial parser that delivers `""` as its result. If you are not familiar with applicative functors you can read about them on [typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia).